# How to store unserializable object between http requests in PHP?

Tags: php, listener, daemon

In my web application I use [Amazon ECS PHP Class](https://github.com/Exeu/Amazon-ECS-PHP-Library/) to get data about Amazon products. Currently I create new object for each page request. It takes about 1000 ms to initialize object and 100 ms to get data from Amazon.

My question is how to avoid object creation for every user request? I'm not sure it's doable in PHP, so feel free to suggest alternative solutions.

I think I need to create a small program that will run on the server and listen for request from PHP, get data from Amazon and return it back to PHP. Please suggest if I'm right and give me an idea what should I look at?

Comment: It really takes 1sec to create the object?!

Comment: 99% of that time is spent on SoapClient object initialization.

Comment: @vim: Quickly scanning the source it looks to me that the object per-se is not unserializeable by actively preventing serialization. However, it might just be that it needs some little extension by supporting the *sleep* and *wakeup* methods: http://php.net/language.oop5.magic#object.sleep - extend from the base-class and add these for some tests. Serialization might help you to cache the object(s) then, making it's use more flexible in your case(s). You could also add a feature or pull request on github.

Answer (score 2):

Here a few tips that should set you on your way:

- The class you are using is intentionally adding a 1-second delay to avoid hitting the Amazon throttle limit (`AmazonECS::requestDelay($enable = null)`).
- You should not be serializing an instance of AmazonECS, because it's just an interface to the Amazon ECS API, and doesn't contain the data that you want.
- You should cache the results of the requests you perform on your instance of AmazonECS in the user's session.

Here's a rough example (I haven't used AmazonECS before, nor have you provided any of your code):

```
session_start(); // remove this if you are already doing it somewhere else

$amazon = new AmazonECS($accessKey, $secretKey, $country, $associateTag);

$myQuery = 'my query';

if (isset($_SESSION['amazon_ecs_cache'][$myQuery]) {
     // use the cached data in the session
     $myData = $_SESSION['amazon_ecs_cache'][$myQuery];
} else {
     // get the data from amazon
     $myData = $amazon->search($myQuery);
     // cache it so we don't have to get it again next time
     $_SESSION['amazon_ecs_cache'][$myQuery] = $myData;
}

// do fun stuff with $myData here
var_dump($myData);
```

Comment: 1. There is 1-second delay in performSoapRequest() function, but this function is not called when we initialize object.

Answer (score 1):

If the object you want to serialize is unserializeable, just create an object that *is* serializeable and carries the values you're actually interested in.